# How to npm install a module without installing peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to npm install `karma-jasmine` and for some odd purpose only want to npm install that module and not karma. It install karma as well as it is defined as a peerDependency. Is it possible to not install peerDependency and how? I am using npm 1.4.28

This is my package.json

```
{"dependencies": {"karma-jasmine": "0.2.3"}}
```

Comment: As a boring workaround, you could just manually remove the dependent module after it was automatically installed.

Comment: You could create an npm shrinkwrap, though it would be a very manual process unless you're ok with installing it normally, then modifying the shrinkwrap to not include karma. Then, future npm installs won't install karma.

Comment: Problem is windows. npm install karma makes such huge folders that when I try to delete karma it cannot because the file path is too long.

Comment: @KevinB npm-shrinkwrap does not work

Comment: Yeah, that windows restriction sucks. I get by it by deleting it using windows explorer or rimraf.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update to newer npm, let say version >=3 ? It does not install peerDependencies by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--omit` option to avoid installing peer dependencies.

```
npm install --omit peer
```

It's important to note, the **package-lock.json** file will be updated to reflect the peer dependencies that *would* have been installed, but the actual dependencies won't be installed.